# how to install codeigniter on 1and1 (Ionos)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I develop for the first time a site in PHP, I do not master this language correctly and I would like to know how to install Codeigniter on 1and1 hosting (Ionos). Thank you for your help

Comment: installation? if its linux based, then u just need to deploy web files and database on 1and1

Comment: that's what I did but nothing is displayed.

To quickly explain my problem, the goal is to run this script  https://codecanyon.net/item/true-bus-online-bus-booking/17280274  When I put the files on 1and1, it does not work. I think I'm doing something wrong but I do not know what.

Comment: Depends, does you package have SSH access? If so you can do it just like you would on yuor local PC, using GIT and composer

Comment: check either php installed or not, please discuss with your server provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to upload entire file/script using FTP to your hosting server and upload your database as well (usually using PHPMyAdmin from cPanel).

If you already have your configuration file done (MySQL username, password, and database name) but problem still occurs, I highly suggest you to reach their technical support.